Why can Sebastian Sallow see Thestrals?
I've chosen for Sebastian Sallow to take me to Hogsmeade and on the way there, Sebastian casually mentions that he's able to see Thestrals.
As far as I understand, one can only see a Thestral if you've witnessed the death of someone.
Why is Sebastian Sallow able to see Thestrals? Who has he witnessed the death of? What happened?

I think because he witnessed the death of his parents. Sebastian and his sister Anne were orphaned at a young age, having seen their parents die. This traumatic experience allows him to see Thestrals, as Thestrals are visible only to those who have witnessed the death of another person.

Relevant source: Hogwarts Legacy fandom
